# Mysql exclude saturday where another value is equal to

Tags: mysql

Im having a little trouble coming to the correct syntax for my code to do what I want. Im summing up numbers of hour worked in a specific week by an employee, but I want to exclude certain days from my query. The employee can have worked for different clients, which are defined by a client_id.

Now the code below have a syntax error in the WHERE-statements inside the parantheses, and I know why, Ill just let them be there for the sake of explaining what I want to achieve in this case.

I appreciate any help you can give me.

Btw: I also tried AND( DAYOFWEEK(date) <> 7 AND client_id = '1' ) but this doesnt work either. I recon this is because my query return just a single line of result, and thus my above code doesnt do anything while the query is loop

```
SELECT
    date,
    client_id,
    SUM(hours)-37.5 AS total,
    SUM(lunch = 'yes') AS lunch
FROM
    hours
WHERE
    CONCAT(WEEK(date, 1)) = '25'
AND
    CONCAT(YEAR(date)) = '2015'
AND
    employee_id = '14'
AND ( DAYOFWEEK(date) <> 7 WHERE client_id = '1' )  
AND ( DAYOFWEEK(date) <> 1 WHERE client_id = '2' ) 
AND
    status = 'billed'
HAVING SUM(hours) > 37.5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a bunch of logical `not` and `and` logical operators to build this logic:

```
SELECT
    date,
    client_id,
    SUM(hours)-37.5 AS total,
    SUM(lunch = 'yes') AS lunch
FROM
    hours
WHERE
    CONCAT(WEEK(date, 1)) = '25'
AND
    CONCAT(YEAR(date)) = '2015'
AND
    employee_id = '14'
AND NOT ( DAYOFWEEK(date) = 7 AND client_id = '1' )  
AND NOT ( DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1 AND client_id = '2' ) 
AND
    status = 'billed'
HAVING SUM(hours) > 37.5
```